# innerhtml is ignoring HTML escaped characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div like

```
<div id="first"></div>
```

and I try to change content (which I get from backend html escaped) as

```
$( "#first" ).html( "Some text <div style=&#34;font-size:150%&#34;>This text should look bigger</div>" );
```

----------OR------------

```
$( "#first" ).html( "Some text <div style=&quot;font-size:150%&quot;>This text should look bigger</div>" );
```

The output in browser is

```
<div id="first">Some text <div style="&quot;font-size:150%&quot;">This text should look bigger</div></div>
```

This is not applying the style I wanted to apply as in the DOM I see two times " (quote). I also tried the classic way of **document.getElementById** with out any success.

Thank's in advance for any idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can decode escaped text with this function:

```
function htmlDecode(value) {
    if (value) {
        return $('<div />').html(value).text();
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

You should pass escaped HTML from the backend through this function before writing it to the page.

Comment: The problem is the server is giving him &quot;. escaping it with \ on the client side won't fix that. I'd suggest making it clear that this solution requires modification of how the server is returning the data (if that's what you're suggesting)